# Custom Page Printing in Crystal Report in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-2008

I have created a crystal-report in which I used a custom page(e.g voucher having width: 8.50 In and height: 5.84 In) created in my default printer.

The problem is that when I run the application from code it sets the page which I gave in default setting of my Crystal Report.But after publishing on IIS it's being printed on A4 page not on page defined.

Looking for valuable solutions of yours

Thanks in advance,

Supriya

Comment: are you publishing from your mcahine or any other machine? and after publishing your are running on your machine or any other machine?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the printer is taking the default settings of the printer. 
Try setting the page margins from code itself.

```
            PageMargins pgMargins = this.CrystalReportDoc.PrintOptions.PageMargins;
            pgMargins.topMargin = <top margin here>;
            pgMargins.bottomMargin = <bottom margin here>;
            this.CrystalReportDoc.PrintOptions.ApplyPageMargins(pgMargins);
```

Also the measurement you had to give should be in twips, you can use an online one like [this](http://www.unitconversion.org/length/inchs-to-twips-conversion.html) for that